# Cross-domain AJAX With ActiveXObject on IE

Tags: javascript

Using the ActiveXObject object on IE. How can I submit a cross-domain request?

Answer (score 2):

Setup a server-side proxy to make the request for you.  Then invoke the proxy (locally) using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using a javascript framework when dealing with ajax request. That way you don't have to get into the intricaties of each browser. My personal favorite is jQuery: http://www.jquery.com/

Now, when it comes to cross-domain, you have two situations:

- Data is only available as XML => use a server-side proxy: http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Cross-Domain_Proxy.php
- Data can be retrieved as JSON using JSONP: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Whenever possible, when it comes to a web browser, I'd recommend JSONP for its simplicity. However, things can get tricky in case of error so, again for jQuery, I'd recommend the following plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/